# Strange packet loss issue

Tags: networking, router, streaming, wireshark

I'm really struggling to track down the cause of a packet loss issue on my home network (BT Infinity FTTC).  It started happening suddenly yesterday morning and is manifesting itself in 3 ways:

1. Timeout exceptions in a Java-based unit-testing application which repeatedly connects to different pages on a particular website.  Quite regularly (i.e. way more often than ever before) it is now saying that the page did not load, which means it's timing out after 20 seconds.  I'm sure this isn't a problem at the website's end.
2. Delayed updates and timeouts in another Java application when trying to consume a streaming API.  It's a financial trading API which broadcasts data whenever there is a change and updates are usually instantaneous.  I can basically see that my application is trying to work with old data because updates are so delayed and every so often the application will completely restart because of a long delay in receiving a keep-alive heartbeat from the server.
3. When streaming media from a server on the network to a client (i.e. this is purely on the LAN, unlike the other two scenarios), basically the media stutters a lot and eventually just freezes.

All of the above have worked fine for a long time (i.e. years) up to now.  The "server" is a Win10 Pro machine.

Here's what I've tried so far to figure out what's going on:

- Pinging the unit-testing website, the streaming api, the media client and local loopback address from my server.  Result:  Completely normal, very low ping times and no packet loss whatsoever
- Taking the server out of the equation by migrating the two applications mentioned above to another machine on the network (a Win10 laptop on WiFi, just to test that aspect too).  Result:  Same issues and errors
- Swapped the router (BT Smart Hub) for another (an older BT Home Hub 5).  I was so sure this would be the issue (especially because I noticed the router firmware had had an update yesterday morning), but the same problems manifested themselves on the new router.
- Ran a Wireshark trace while trying to stream media as in scenario 3 above.  Result:  A lot of dup ack and retransmission messages when the issue is ongoing.

Sorry for the wordy explanation; I've basically been going round in circles with this for a while now.  I can't see how it's an ISP issue given that the problem happens on the LAN too.  It's also not specific to my usual server or router.  Very briefly it will start working absolutely fine again, then back to problems again half an hour or so later.

It's very bizarre.  Any suggestions on anything else at all to look at would be very welcome.

Comment: For scenario 3, is it purely over wired lan? Retransmission is usually due to timeouts at one end or the other (syn's or ack's being repeated) and if over wireless this could simply be external interference (which would explain why it's not gone away with any of the changes you've tried). If it's wired.... can you run a new wire just to test for the time being, it's possible that something has started interfering on the existing wire. Also, has _anything_ changed recently. I'm presuming this is all in a home - so lots of things could of changed...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I was as specific as I could be in my original post without some input from the community.  Thanks for providing that; I have added the info you would find useful to my question.

Comment: So basically you need to determine where the packet loss is occurring, this sounds like a job for PingPlotter. https://www.pingplotter.com/

Comment: @djsmiley2k Yes purely over wired LAN.  I'll try some new cables, starting with server -> router as I guess that's the only shared route in all 3 scenarios.

It is a home network but I would (tentatively!) say that nothing could have changed, i.e. no new hardware has been added, nothing has been moved, unplugged, etc.

Comment: Could the my on one of the systems changed (maybe a software patch enabling jumbo frames or something?)

Comment: Possibly a duplex mis-match.

Comment: @davidgo: I had a look at MTU sizes.  I tested the max allowable on the BT Smart Hub and it's 1492.  That's how the other machines are set too.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart:  The symptoms are definitely similar to a Duplex mismatch; my NIC was set to auto-negotiate so I tried setting manually to 1Gbps Full Duplex, but no change to the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @djsmiley2k: New cables didn't help either sadly!  And there were no Windows update patches installed on the day this all started.

Comment: I've now done some testing with PingPlotter (thanks @acejavelin). The issue only happens when running the API app I described in scenario 2 in my OP.  And it's only killing the connection on the machine it runs on.  I ran PingPlotter on the server and laptop at the same time and on whichever machine the app was running, eventually latency went through the roof and everything ground to a halt, but the other machine was still fine.

Problem is, nothing has changed in that application (or the API it talks to) for several months and it ran 24/7 without issues up until Saturday!

Comment: Well... i was going to tell you to try another NIC. but after your last comments its clear to me this is related to the application you are running. as the problem seems to be following the program around from computer to computer. (you didn't tell us what it is you are actually running.) normally with no service-pack updates, or no changes to the host OS, we can pretty much assume there is a bug in the program. sometimes it manifests itself as a bloated temporary file. i would focus on inspecting the program and any related files / temporary files and clear what you can.

Comment: If this is a program you had someone write for you, or you wrote it yourself. It may not be a bad idea to ask at stack overflow, if you are willing to reveal the source to what you are running that is.

Comment: It did seem like the application was causing it, however last night I moved it to a VPS in the cloud (a lower spec one than mine at home at that) and it's been running happily again ever since.  Interestingly in the process of moving it, I had to transfer some large files to the VPS via RDP, and doing so killed all http traffic on my home network (all machines this time).  The files kept transferring fine but the latency on the TCP pings I'd set up in PingPlotter went through the roof again and no websites were accessible.  So there does seem to be some weird network-related issue going on...

Comment: You may want to try and push the upper limit of the router. Use jperf to create testing traffic. See if you can replicate what's actually causing this on your home network. You should be able to isolate what device is causing the issue.